# WPF Datagrid Template Combobox does not show data when the rest of the datagrid does

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I have an simple SQL database with an EF model and a dataset set to the table objects of the model. If I drag and drop a datagid from the 'Customers' table in the datasource all works fine. But if i change the 'State' field to a combobox before drag and dropping the datagrid, I cannot get the combobox to show data from the database whatever i try.
I have the itemsource of the combobox set to a static resource list defined in the Application.Resources in app.xaml as follows:-

```
<Application.Resources>
<x:Array x:Key="StateListString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "ACT"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "QLD"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "NSW"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "NT"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "SA"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "TAS"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "VIC"/>
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "WA"/>
</x:Array>
```

My XAML Page is-

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:Generic="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AthenaArt" x:Class="AthenaArt.CustomerPage" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="650" d:DesignWidth="1200"
Title="CustomerPage" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customerViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Customer}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource customerViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="customerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/-->
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="firstNameColumn" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="companyNameColumn" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Header="Company Name" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Address" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="address2Column" Binding="{Binding Address2}" Header="Address 2" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="suburbColumn" Binding="{Binding Suburb}" Header="Suburb" Width="110"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="stateColumn" Header="State" Width="80">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <ComboBox x:Name="cboState" Initialized="cbo_Initialized"
                                  ItemsSource ="{StaticResource StateListString}"  
                                  IsEditable="False"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="ValueString"
                                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = "False"
                                  SelectedValuePath ="ValueString" 
                                  Width="Auto">
                        </ComboBox>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="postCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding PostCode}" Header="Post Code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailColumn" Binding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Phone" Width="90"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="mobileColumn" Binding="{Binding Mobile}" Header="Mobile" Width="90"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="notesColumn" Binding="{Binding Notes}" Header="Notes" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

My code behind is -

```
namespace AthenaArt
{ 
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CustomerPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CustomerPage : Page //This page is loaded into a ribbon window on the Main Window
    {
        private Athena_ArtEntities _context = new Athena_ArtEntities();

        public CustomerPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal void SaveCustomer()//Called from a button on the main window
        {
           //Commit the newly entered row
            this.customerDataGrid.CommitEdit();
           _context.SaveChanges();

            // Refresh the grid so the database generated values show up. All do except the combobox values
            this.customerDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }

        internal void AddCustomer()
        {
          // TODO
        }

        internal void LoadData()
        {
             System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource customerViewSource =
           ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("customerViewSource")));

            _context.Customers.Load();

            customerViewSource.Source = _context.Customers.Local; 
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            LoadData();
        }   
    }
}

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using AthenaArt; 
namespace AthenaArt 
{ 
    public class ComboBoxItemString 
    { 
        public string ValueString { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Changes to the combobox field are written back to the database correctly and by implementing UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the SelectedValue binding the values are not disappearing after I save the grid. However, the values do not populate when the grid is loaded. I am tearing my hair out at this point and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I assume the data type could be an issue. what is the data type of `State`? if it is string then try using `sys:String` instead of `local:ComboBoxItemString` where namespace sys: is referring to `mscorlib`. secondly the posted code behind does not have any relevance to the issue, you may remove it and perhaps add the model class for `Athena_ArtEntities` or the State property if you think may help.

Comment: sys:String cannot be used as binding has to bind to an object! ComboBoxString provides the object as follows

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AthenaArt;

namespace AthenaArt
{
   
        public class ComboBoxItemString
        {
            public string ValueString { get; set; }
        }

   
}

Comment: The State value is being populated and saved to the DB OK. It is just not populating the control when the rest of the row is populated from the DB.